# Isotope responsive behaving strangely on really big screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I have added isotope to a portfolio website that is responsive and it's doing something strange. I want it to be 3 columns unless I am on a 980px resolution where I want it to be just one. The thing is at really high resolutions (over 2000px) I am getting just one colum but at the same width if they where 3 (33.333%) so it's neither one thing or the other. I can't find out what is making the change, I inspect the css and I see no clue that is causing this.

Also the width at which this is happening isn't consistent. I have seen this happen as soon as I get 2000px resolution and the next time it won't until it's 2200 o rsomething like that. I tried to reproduce it in a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zUfce/8/

But you can see my preprod site in http://www.vitaminalemon.com/bm2/trabajos/

My isotope script:

```
var $container = $('#container');
    function resize_element(){
        var height=$('.element').width();
        $('.element').height(height);
    }
    resize_element();

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.element',
        animationEngine: 'best-available',
        filter: '.destacados',
        resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3 }
    });
    $(window).smartresize(function(){
        resize_element();
      $container.isotope({
        // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3 }
      });
    });

    function initialize() {
       var divH = $('.proyect-title p').innerHeight()/2;
       var pageH = $('.proyect-title').innerHeight()/2;
      $('.proyect-title p').css({top: (pageH-divH)});
    }

    initialize();

    $(window).on('resize',function(){
      initialize();
    });


  var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
    var options = {},
        key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
        value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
    // parse 'false' as false boolean
    value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
    options[ key ] = value;
    if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
      // changes in layout modes need extra logic
      changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
    } else {
      // otherwise, apply new options
      $container.isotope( options );
    }

    return false;
  });
```

And my scss added for this (that is not the isotope css)

```
.element{
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            background: #000;
            color: #fff;
    img{
        @include opacity(0.4);
        @include transition-property(opacity);
        @include transition-duration(1s); 
    }
    &:hover img, &.active-tag img{
        @include opacity(0.8);
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: #{$small-screen}){

    .element{
        width: 33.3333%;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can rule out the `media` query for starters. I set the container to yellow when the filter kicks in and it was unrelated so I removed the filter completely and problem remains. If you just set it to 33% all the time you still get the same issue of it dropping to one column on large widths. Still investigating...

Comment: +1 for very good JSFiddle. Makes it so much easier to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically getting one problem twice. A rounding error.

By using /3 for the width it can actually wind up with only 2 columns that fit the container.

Then by using 33.3333% as the element width, this actually exceeds one isotope column width (very slightly) and causes only a single column (of the two that fit) to display.

Change it to 33.3% and it works fine:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  #trabajos .element {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
```

### JSiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zUfce/10/

Comment: Yeah I added those extra .33 because I was seeing a small gap between the columns but whatever, I'll try your solution

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I find it really weird that this issue appeared on random widths, now I know why. Thanks!